# Show MBProgressHUD when Perform Segue

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios7, mbprogresshud

How can I show MBProgressHUD when  perform `segue` to navigate between `ViewControllers` ?

Comment: you cant do like that with MBProgressHUD, but you create you own and to add it to window instead of Controller View to show even when perform seque.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to show the HUD in the destination ViewController

put the HUD show code in:

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

//MBProgressHUD code

}

This work for me.